# Select characters and wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to wrap the last 2 characters in a piece of text in a `<sup>` using jQuery. I can do a `console.log` that returns the text I want to wrap, but it never gets wrapped. The code I have is really simple:

```
// get text of heading
var plansBlockHeading = $('.first .sub .one h4').text();

// filter to last 2 chars
var sup = plansBlockHeading.substr(plansBlockHeading.length-2); 

// Wrap in a <sup></sup>
$(sup).wrap("<sup />");
```

I'm obviously missing something simple, but I'm not sure what. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you reinsert that into the DOM, or do you just expect the string you just wrapped to magically appear on the screen ?

Comment: Look's like you are wrapping the text but not appending it anywhere into your DOM.. Also the selector has to be a HTML structure or a element.. You seem to wrap just plain text.. Try appending it directly into a element instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idiomatic jQuery solution could look like this:

```
$('.first .sub .one h4').html(function(i, html) {
       // make sure there's no whitespace issues
    html = $.trim(html);
    return html.slice(0, -2) + "<sup>" + html.slice(-2) + "</sup>";
});
```

This assumes there's no HTML markup inside the `h4` *(really just at the end would be an issue)*.

This also handles properly if you have more than one `h4`.

Comment: This works perfectly, and it is the most elegant solution in my opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var elem = $('.first .sub .one h4'),
    text = elem.text(),
    html = text.slice(0,-2) + '<sup>' + text.slice(-2) + '</sup>';
elem.html(html);​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDauH/1/)

Comment: You're replacing all the content with only the last two characters and the new element. I don't think that's what is wanted.

Comment: @user1689607 - you're probably right, but that's what the OP is doing in the question, so who knows ?

Comment: @adeneo: yes, this is replacing everything. No, that's not what I'm trying to do in the question - that's the point of asking - to get help; passive aggressiveness not needed.

Comment: I think OP sees the JS/DOM as a single live environment rather than two separate bridged environments that need explicit communication. Would be nice if we could see live updates of all our manipulations. :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a regexp

```
var text = $('.first .sub .one h4').text();
text = text.replace(/^(.*)(.{2,2})$/, "$1<sup>$2</sup>");
$('.first .sub .one h4').html(text);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evPhf/

Comment: Regex seems like overkill doesn't it? I mean you know exactly which characters are wanted, and they're right at the end. Also, you should be using `.html()` instead of `text()` to set the new content, unless you want to see the markup. Finally, if there's any other markup inside the `h4`, it'll be lost.

Comment: It's a simple solution to a simple question. If the question mentioned the h4 having html I would include that.

Comment: Looks like regex abuse to me. Also, it will fail when the text inside the `h4` includes line breaks before the last 2 characters.